# Deploying R Markdown File with Shiny Component

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

Building off my previous question, I'm having trouble creating a ***DEPLOYABLE*** R Markdown file that has a Shiny component JUST to allow user to upload an Excel workbook.
Essentially, I want to run Python code on top of the data that the user provides.

This doesn't seem to deploy correctly to RConnect (it just times out):

```
---
output: html_document
---

library(dplyr)
library(miniUI)
library(shiny)
library(XLConnect)

launch_shiny <- function() {

  ui <- miniPage(
    gadgetTitleBar("Input Data"),
    miniContentPanel(
      fileInput(inputId = "my.file", label = NULL, 
                multiple = FALSE)
    )
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    wb <- reactive({
      new.file <- input$my.file
      loadWorkbook(
        filename = new.file$datapath,
        create = FALSE,
        password = NULL
      )
    })

    # ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    df_lst <- reactive({
      # read all sheets into a list
      lapply(getSheets(wb()), 
             function(sheet){
               readWorksheet(object = wb(), 
                             sheet = sheet)
             })
    })
   # ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    observeEvent(input$done, {
      # get the list of dfs from the app
      stopApp(c(df_lst())) 
    })

  }
  runGadget(ui, server)
  }

test <- launch_shiny()
```

If I add `runtime: shiny` at the beginning, it would fail as `runGadget` uses `runApp`, which is also used by `shiny`; however, I need to make sure that I can return a variable (in this case, list of data frames) to the global environment, which is why I was using `stopApp`.

What are my options at this point?

Comment: You are trying to build and Rmarkdown document including a shiny app without the shiny runtime... It looks like what you really want is a [parametrised Rmarkdown document](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/params-knit.html) so users can upload the file before knitting.

Comment: @JohnCoene Well, I need them to upload the file AFTER I knit, which is the problem. I don't want them to install R/Python/IDEs to run my code.

Comment: This can't be done. If you want to actually create a static html document with an input you would have to do the processing in JavaScript and not R.

Comment: Hmm.. if I define `runtime: shiny`, I can't use `stopApp` without stopping the entire thing. If I don't define it and use Shiny inside RMarkdown, it only seems to work on local machine. `Shiny` doesn't seem to support `reticulate` very well. Jupyter notebook doesn't seem to have extensions which would allow user to upload Excel workbooks. Guess I'm stuck :)

Comment: I'm very confused about what you want. Your question starts with "deploy" which implies the use of a server where you could run shiny and therefore use a parametrised Rmarkdown report or even a shiny application, which could optionally enable users to download a report. But you want a static file that knitted on the user machine (why?) Then take an input, then (I assume) display something different. I think you misunderstand shiny and Rmarkdown. You don't need to place a whole shiny app in a report (particularly with `runGadet`) to receive user inputs.

Comment: If I'm reading the document correctly, even with `output: html_document`, if we specify `runtime: shiny`, Shiny interactions occur on the server side: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-14.html

Comment: Yes, and if you don’t have the shiny runtime you don’t have a server. I.e.: server function can’t possible run.

Comment: I essentially want an interactive markdown document or Shiny app which can deploy on RConnect, read in user workbook, and run Python code. I know the difference between Shiny and RMarkdown (though I haven't touched RMD in a while and it's changed significantly); the main problem I'm having is passing user input into global environment to pass onto `py` object to leverage `reticulate`.

Comment: Just wanted to correct myself; it seems like it wasn’t an issue with RMD or Shiny, but rather an issue trying to use `py` object interactively with `reticulate`.
I’m able to launch a Shiny App with `reticulate` and also RMD with the Shiny App embedded in it.